# how to run four macros by click one button?

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

i have four groups of shapes. And each group got 6 shapes, and i would like to random choose one of 6 shapes in each group. And because i got four groups, which means every time i click a button, 4 shapes will be random chose from 4 groups respectively. 
I have searched online but couldn't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 0):

how to run four macros by click one button?

1. Combine all the code from 1-4 into a new macro, #5, and assign it a shortcut key
2. Create macro #5 to  execute macro #1,#2,#3,#4